# When should I use an HTML comment over a server comment?

Tags: asp.net, html

From what I understand HTML comments cause longer load time so why would one use them instead of server comments which are never sent to the client?

Comment: when you're commenting on the markup instead of the backend code, and need that comment.

Answer (score 0):

While server comments are usually more efficient in terms of page load times, HTML comments are sometimes necessary when you want to print a comment inside a loop and view it after having it rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You use `html` comments when you are not using any serverside code "near" your comment, just for convenience.

Or as mentioned in the other answer as debug output.

Another reason to use `html` comments is to present **easter eggs** to users that take the effort to see your code.

Last but not least, there are [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) that work for our friendly IE browser. These comments are very useful html comments (and should therefor perhaps not be named comment).